# SAT question, what choice could fit into this context?

Tags: grammar, expressions, syntactic-analysis

For question 37, the answer is C, but I chose B. I just don't know how B is wrong. The rest of the paragraph indeed is talking about the display of clothes with technology way, which is quite creative.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have to look at the text a few times, so I can see how you made the mistake but I did, at last, understand the reason for their choice.

The point is that the paragraph concentrates on a particular exhibition of the work of Charles James and speaks in detail about his work so, to be consistent, C is the best choice since it mentions James and his work whereas B talks about the display of costume in general.

I think part of the trouble that we both had was that we were looking at each question separately rather than reading the whole text through first then taking the questions in context.

Having said that this question is much more a matter of opinion than 36 and 37 which are simple questions of grammar and the right choice of words.

Comment: If C is their 'best choice', that does not make B wrong. B is correct about the display, but C explains why.

Comment: @YosefBaskin We get quite a few of these SAT questions that seem to be based on shades of opinion rather than definite right or wrong answers. I often wonder who sets the questions.

Comment: The SAT rules ask for the *best* answer, not the correct one. Add that challenge of shades of meaning to the time pressure, and you know teens are stressed. In Math, 50% of 1 is of course 1/2, but an answer like 5/10 is right but not simplified (a math and SAT standard). So while 1/2 and 5/10 are both right, one is the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think part of the trouble that we both had was that we were looking at each question separately rather than reading the whole text through first then taking the questions in context.

Comment: Are you quoting part of my answer in order to disagree with it or otherwise comment on it, Michel? If so you need to make your point. As it stands this is not an answer to the question.